# How to access dynamic div inside any div using CSS

Tags: css

I have a situation where I need to access a div which is dynamically generated by jQuery mobile.
**How can I access this using CSS ? I need to change UI of the inside div.**
Following is the HTML structure.

```
<div id="myCreatedDiv">
    <div class="jQueryMobileCreatedDiv">
        /* I need to access this div */
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: Above structure I found in chrome's element inspector
My original code is as follows

```
<div id="one" class="myDiv" ui-body-d ui-content">
    <input name="anyName" id="jQueryTextBox"/>
</div>
```

It would be very helpful if anyone can help me for the same.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You select the div in exactly the same way you would any other: `.myCreatedDiv .jQueryMobileCreatedDiv { /* styling here... */ }`

Comment: .jQueryMobileCreatedDiv  is dynamically generated div. It is generated by jQueryMobile framework at runtime

Comment: That's fine - the CSS rules are applied dynamically. You just need to write the correct selector in your CSS

Comment: I need to update those CSS rules which are applied by jQuery mobile

Comment: And I, along with most of the answers below, have told you how to do that

Comment: you are not understanding the question properly,  I the ".jQueryMobileCreatedDiv" is just mentioned to indicate that this div is generated by jQuery Mobile framework. which is not exist at design time, so how can I apply your suggestion at design time?

Comment: Well obviously that was an example. You just need to change that selector to match whatever ***is*** being generated. You haven't shown what that is in your quesiton so none of us can spoonfeed you that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can acces div inside `.jQueryMobileCreatedDiv` is like this:

```
var divInside = $('.jQueryMobileCreatedDiv').children("div");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however can you tell me that How can I access this using CSS, actually I need to change the UI.

Comment: means do you want to change css of div?

Comment: Yes, I need to change CSS for the div

Comment: You can do like:  `$('.jQueryMobileCreatedDiv').children("div").css("width","50px")`

Comment: @DharaParmar I think you're misunderstanding the question. The OP wants to target the element in CSS. Nothing to do with jQuery here.

Comment: I assume you mean downvote, and if so, no it wasn't me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS selector:

```
#myCreatedDiv > div { /* Your CSS here */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

```
$('#myCreatedDiv').find('#one');

or

$('.jQueryMobileCreatedDiv').parents('#myCreatedDiv').find('#one');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class of the generated div

```
#myCreatedDiv > .jQueryMobileCreatedDiv {

}
```